# Redirect desktop users away from mobile site with .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mobile, user-agent

Hello Folks at Stackoverflow,

I'm looking to redirect desktop users away from mobile site with .htaccess:

I already have this code which works perfectly when a mobile user tries to access the mobile version of my website example: m.website.com.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^desktop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|#opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.website.com [L,R=302]
```

However if a user types m.website.com on a desktop browser, it goes directly to the mobile version content.

Is there a way to add any additional code to the .htaccess file to make it work in a way that when a desktop user attempts to go to m.website.com it remains in the desktop version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this additional rule in `.htaccess` of `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of `m.website.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera\smobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

Comment: anubhava Thanks for your follow up on my request. Where do I specifically need to place the url on this rule:

Comment: I am capturing URL that comes `m.(website.com)` so request will be redirected to `http://website.com/some-path` but main website address is not available in mobile website then feel free to replace `%1` above with whatever your website address is.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, I changed my desktop rule to:                         RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|#opera mobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]                       And still the redireccion from http://m.website.com (mobile) to http://website.com (desktop) isn't working. I do not know what I'm doing wrong on this process... does the .htaccess file should be in the desktop directory or on the m. (mobile subdomain)

Comment: This `.htaccess` should be in `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of `m.website.com`

Comment: I went ahead and placed in the the DOCUMENT_ROOT of m.website.com and I got the following error: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@m.axikmobile.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

Comment: Did you add `RewriteEngine On` on top?

Comment: Yes, like this:                                                                             RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|#opera mobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://axikmobile.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

Comment: Make sure that you have `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` enabled on `m.` host?

Comment: This is the result that I am trying to achieve go to http://m.kbb.com and it automatically redirects you to http://www.kbb.com. How do I check if mod_rewrite is enabled on m. ? Thanks for all this support and follow up.

Comment: You can ask your server admin or create a PHP file with code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and check its output.

Comment: I created the php file on .m root and did not see anything regarding with mod_rewrite being enabled.

Comment: Well obviously `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` will need to be enabled for these rules. If you own Apache config and then enable it otherwise contact your server admin.

Comment: Your `phpinfo` output doesn't have Apache modules listed so we can't say for sure. Let's create an empty .htaccess wit just line line `RewriteEngine On` and see if error goes away.

Comment: I created the empty .htaccess with just one line that says: RewriteEngine On and the error went away. I am talking to my server admin and he says "those are currently active on your account".

Comment: I just found a mistake in USER_AGENT. You had `opera mobile` with a space and that was causing 500 error. I fixed it by making `opera\smobile`. Try edited code at same place (m site), it should work for you.

Comment: he showed me he got this error :
[Fri Sep 27 16:05:52 2013] [alert] [client 69.195.67.179] /home2/miprimer/public_html/m/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters. he also said that There are some (probably) unwanted spaces in the regexes

Comment: Yes see my previous comment, that space things has been fixed now.

Comment: Hello Anubhava... THANK YOU FOR ALL YOUR HELP..! You are the best!!! I was so confident and thank you for your patience.. It worked now!!!!

Comment: RewriteEngine On
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} m [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|#operamobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

Comment: Hello Anubhava... I need your help again.. with an other thing I am trying to figure out about creating a rule with htaccess.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} http://domain.com/subdomain [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|ipad|#operamobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

Comment: Don't put a new question in comments. Suggest you to create a new question and I will attend it.